# Functional way to parse nested dictionary into array of each level's elements

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

I'd like to solve a problem in a functional style in javascript.

My dict looks like this:

```
[{
    "title": "A",
    "isFinal": false,
    "children": [{
            "title": "AA",
            "isFinal": false,
            "children": [{
                    "title": "AAA",
                    "isFinal": true
                },
                {
                    "title": "AAB",
                    "isFinal": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "AB",
            "isFinal": false,
            "children": [{
                    "title": "ABA",
                    "isFinal": true
                },
                {
                    "title": "ABB",
                    "isFinal": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "AC",
            "isFinal": true
        }
    ]
}]
```

So this is a tree and it can have up to N (6) levels and many more leaves in any node. The final node has `isFinal` field set to true.

I'd like to have the following output

```
[["A"], ["AA", "AB", "AC"], ["AAA", "AAB", "ABA", "ABB"]]
```

which is a title from every node on the same level in the same array.

I think it has somehow related to algorithm recursive descent but I can't figure it out.

So far I can access the first level:

```
function parseData (data) {
    const data = new Array();

    return data.filter((dataLevelChild) => (!dataLevelChild.isFinal)).map((dataLevelChild, index) => (
      dataLevelChild.title
    ))
}
```

but I don't really know how to pass the second-level elements and store everything in one array.

Another way is to use forEach

```
function parseData (data) {
    const parsedData = new Array();

    const parse = (e) => {
      parsedData.push({
          id: e.title,
      });

      e.children && e.children.forEach(parse);
  }

  return data.forEach(parse);
```

which is not correct but at least I have the access to each element. Is it functional though? It doesn't look like to me because usually you don't use .push like this in functional style

Comment: You need a recursive function to deal with arbitrary nesting. Doing this with functional programming will be tricky.

Comment: @Barmar: why do you say that?  Recursion is an extremely common technique in FP.  My answer for instance, is an FP solution.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I know recursion is common in FP, but it seemed like it would be tricky to get the all results of a particular recursion level into the appropriate array element in the final result.

Comment: @Barmar: that was the only thing that slowed me down at all, building this atop my usual breadth-first traversal code.  I needed to think a little about where those extra `[` - `]` brackets would go.  But the code ends up fairly clean.

Answer (score 2):

You could collect all nested levels and assign next level's titles to the collecting array.

```js
const
    getTitles = data => data.reduce((r, { title, children }) => {
        (r[0] ??= []).push(title);
        if (children) getTitles(children)
            .forEach((a, i) => (r[i + 1] ??= []).push(...a));
        return r;
    }, []),
    data = [{ title: "A", isFinal: false, children: [{ title: "AA", children: [{ title: "AAA", isFinal: true }, { title: "AAB", isFinal: true }] }, { title: "AB", children: [{ title: "ABA", isFinal: true }, { title: "ABB", isFinal: true }] }, { title: "AC", isFinal: true }] }],
    result = getTitles(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach by collecting titles and children separately and get the children in another call of the function.

```js
const
    getTitles = data => {
        const [titles, children] = getPairs(data);
        return children.length
            ? [titles, ...getTitles(children)]
            : [titles];
    },
    getPairs = data => data.reduce(
        ([t, c], { title, children = [] }) => [[...t, title], [...c, ...children]],
        [[], []]
    ),
    data = [{ title: "A", isFinal: false, children: [{ title: "AA", children: [{ title: "AAA", isFinal: true }, { title: "AAB", isFinal: true }] }, { title: "AB", children: [{ title: "ABA", isFinal: true }, { title: "ABB", isFinal: true }] }, { title: "AC", isFinal: true }] }],
    result = getTitles(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: While this code, as always, is elegant, the OP did specifically ask for a functional programming solution.  Between the calls to `push` and the `forEach`, I don't think this qualifies.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, please have a look to the second code snippet.

Comment: Yes, that is a much more functional approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use recursion:

```js
function myFunc(arr = []){
  let toRet = [];
  function recursion(obj = {}, depth){
    toRet[depth] = [...(toRet[depth]|| []), obj.title];
    if(!obj.isFinal){
      obj.children.forEach(el => recursion(el, depth + 1))
    }
  }
  arr.forEach(el => recursion(el, 0))
  return toRet;
}

let input = [{
    "title": "A",
    "isFinal": false,
    "children": [{
            "title": "AA",
            "isFinal": false,
            "children": [{
                    "title": "AAA",
                    "isFinal": true
                },
                {
                    "title": "AAB",
                    "isFinal": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "AB",
            "isFinal": false,
            "children": [{
                    "title": "ABA",
                    "isFinal": true
                },
                {
                    "title": "ABB",
                    "isFinal": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "AC",
            "isFinal": true
        }
    ]
}]
console.log(myFunc(input))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this atop a simple breadth-first traversal.

Here `levelMap` maps a function over all the nested elements, grouping them by level.

And `getTitle` partially applies to the above a function that extracts the titles from the nodes.

```js
const levelMap = (fn) => (xs = []) => 
  xs .length == 0 
    ? [] 
    : [xs .flatMap (x => [fn (x)])]
          .concat (levelMap (fn) (xs .flatMap (({children = []}) => children)))

const getTitles = levelMap (x => x.title)

const input = [{title: "A", isFinal: false, children: [{title: "AA", isFinal: false, children: [{title: "AAA", isFinal: true}, {title: "AAB", isFinal: true}]}, {title: "AB", isFinal: false, children: [{title: "ABA", isFinal: true}, {title: "ABB", isFinal: true}]}, {title: "AC", isFinal: true}]}]

console .log (getTitles (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If you didn't want to group by levels (I usually don't) then you can simply replace

```js
    : [xs .flatMap (x => [fn (x)])]
```

with

```js
    : xs .flatMap (x => [fn (x)])
```

(at which point I would probably rename this to something like `breadthFirstMap`.)

This approach is purely functional.  There is no mutation anywhere, and the functions are pure.

Obviously, you could write a single function that does this, and does away with the `fn` parameter in the process.  But `levelMap` is general-purpose, and it's easy enough to layer our function on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion, as shown in other answers, is a good tool to work with tree structures.

Solving this code challenges with both concise and readable code is very challenging indeed... I am sure my solution can be improved by a lot.

```js
const deepPluck = (prop, tree = []) => {
  const res = [];

  const drilldown = (prop, list, depth) => {    
    for (const item of list) {
      const { children = [], [prop]: plucked } = item;

      res[depth] = (res[depth] ?? []).concat(plucked);
      drilldown(prop, children, depth + 1);
    }
  }

  drilldown(prop, tree, 0);
  return res;
}

// =
const data = [{ title: "A", isFinal: false, children: [{ title: "AA", children: [{ title: "AAA", isFinal: true }, { title: "AAB", isFinal: true }] }, { title: "AB", children: [{ title: "ABA", isFinal: true }, { title: "ABB", isFinal: true }] }, { title: "AC", isFinal: true }] }];

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(deepPluck('title', data)),
);
```